# Checking for unanswered questions in a bash script

Tags: bash, algorithm, text, document

I am trying to write a bash script to scan for unanswered questions. It takes a document as an argument and then scans for text prepended by a single asterisk (this represents a question) on the current line. It then scans the next line after such a question. If it finds double or more asterisks at the start of that next line (this represents an answer) it should disregard the question and the answer, but if instead it finds on the next line another string of text starting with a single asterisk (OR if it finds no asterisk at the start of the following line), it should print the text which follows after the first single asterisk on the current line (this represents an unanswered question).

The algorithm I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <document>"
  exit 1
fi

document="$1"
current_line=""
skip_question=false

while IFS= read -r next_line; do
  if [[ "$current_line" == "* "* ]]; then
    if [[ "$next_line" == "**"* ]]; then
      skip_question=true
    elif [[ "$next_line" == "" || "$next_line" == "*"* ]]; then
      echo "Unanswered Question: ${current_line#* }"
    fi
  fi

  if [ "$skip_question" = false ]; then
    current_line="$next_line"
  else
    skip_question=false
  fi
done < "$document"
```

Using a test document, this does return answers which I can verify are unanswered, but it returns other false positives with questions that have answers following them (and doesn't return other questions which also have answers following them). How can I improve my script to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Walk yourself through a short example document, line by line, and write down the $current_line and $next_line for each iteration of the loop. You will quickly discover the problem.

When $skip_question is true, the $current_line does not advance, and now $current_line is two lines behind $next_line. I don't think this is what you want.

Set $current_line equal to $next_line unconditionally at the end of every iteration. You probably don't need the $skip_question flag at all.